# 'Order' Object not callable, or not defined

Tags: python, json, stock, alpacajs

I am using Python. I have placed a trade to buy a stock. The trade filled. I am getting the order data back to see what price it filled at. I am using that price to generate a sell price.

The issue is, I don't know how to sift through the data and extract the fill price. I don't know enough about coding to even know what to call it so here is the data. I am trying to extract that `29.42` in `filled_avg_price`.

```py
Order({   'asset_class': 'us_equity',
    'asset_id': 'b49cfcfc-b0f7-4bf0-aff8-a33ffe6f0073',
    'canceled_at': None,
    'client_order_id': 'ENPH4',
    'created_at': '2020-04-01T19:27:23.641068Z',
    'expired_at': None,
    'extended_hours': False,
    'failed_at': None,
    'filled_at': '2020-04-01T19:27:23.768187Z',
    'filled_avg_price': '29.42',
    'filled_qty': '1',
    'id': 'a58e92a2-35d5-4d6e-9fcb-03c4c1ee8c65',
    'legs': None,
    'limit_price': '32',
    'order_class': '',
    'order_type': 'limit',
    'qty': '1',
    'replaced_at': None,
    'replaced_by': None,
    'replaces': None,
    'side': 'buy',
    'status': 'filled',
    'stop_price': None,
    'submitted_at': '2020-04-01T19:27:23.184461Z',
    'symbol': 'ENPH',
    'time_in_force': 'day',
    'type': 'limit',
    'updated_at': '2020-04-01T19:27:23.783736Z'})
```

I am using `import alpaca_trade_api` If you need to install it to check things out.

Here is the Order class from there

```py
class Order(Entity):
    def __init__(self, raw):
        super().__init__(raw)
        try:
            self.legs = [Order(o) for o in self.legs]
        except Exception:
            # No order legs existed
            pass
```

Comment: Did you import the Order class?

Comment: i havent. but just did.
my_order= tradeapi.entity.Order(my_order) . I dont know what to do with it now to extract specifics though

Comment: Did you try my_order["status"], etc?

Comment: TypeError: 'Order' object is not subscriptable

Comment: i know theres an easier way, and I'm sticking around to hear it, but I did mess around with it until I got it <blink> my_order = my_order.split() my_order = my_order[20] my_order = my_order[:-2] my_order = my_order[1:] my_order = float(my_order) exit_price = float(1.5) my_order = my_order * exit_price </blink>

Comment: Oh it probably means it's a JSON then. Just use import json and in your code json.loads(order)

Comment: ive tried to decipher exactly what mean and i'm coming up short. Ive done json.loads(my_order). Ive done json.loads(Order(my_order)). ive done json.loads(entity.Order(my_order)). error every time